# How to get details for a testSuite in testlink api?

Tags: java, testlink

I am using testlink java api (https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=testlink-java-api&g=br.eti.kinoshita&v=1.9.2-1) and I am faceing a small but convenient problem.

I am trying to get the details of a test suite which is on TestLink but all I can get is "null".

Here is my code :

```
`TestSuite[] testSuitesInTestPlan = api.getTestSuitesForTestPlan(testPlanId);
    if(testSuitesInTestPlan.length!=0){
        for(int i=0;i<testSuitesInTestPlan.length;i++){
          if(testSuitesInTestPlan[i].getName().compareTo(testSuiteName)==0){
                String answer = testSuitesInTestPlan[i].getDetails();`
```

With this code, the only parameters which are not null in the test suites I am getting are : their name, their id and their parent_id.

Do you have any idea of where I made a mistake ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Finally manage to get all of the details of a test suite in TestLink using the api.getTestSuiteById method :

```
`List<Integer> id = new LinkedList();
id.add(testSuiteId());
String details=api.getTestSuiteByID(id)[0].getDetails();`
```

My problem now is to edit the details of this test suite in TestLink.
I tried the setDetails() method but it does not update the details in TestLink... Do you have any suggestion ?

Thank you